# How to query Prometheus vectors with specific value and with time offset?

Tags: prometheus, promql

In Prometheus, I want to query an instant vector in the past with value equals 1. Can I do that with PromQL or do I need to achieve it with recording rules?

Intuitively, I tried something like:

```
up{instance="192.168.0.100"} == 1 offset 30m
```

But it gives me the error:
"Error executing query: invalid parameter 'query': parse error at char 39: offset modifier must be preceded by an instant or range selector, but follows a *promql.NumberLiteral instead"

I thought it was an operators order issue as the part before `offset` is an instant vector. So I added parentheses:

```
(up{instance="192.168.0.100"} == 1) offset 30m
```

But it gives another error:
"Error executing query: invalid parameter 'query': parse error at char 34: could not parse remaining input "offset 30m"..."

So I'm asking if there is any way to get a vector that the value equals 1 at the time of 30 minutes ago? Do I must use recording rules to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Am not sure about your use-case, but try with something like this:

`(up{instance="localhost:9090",job="prometheus"} offset 30m) == 1`

Comment: A further question, how to make it work when it's not offset but a time range instead? e.g. (up{instance="192.168.0.100"} == 1) [30m] doesn't work

Comment: @jallen0927, if you use timerange it will become range-vector and resultType will be 'matrix'. You cannot use Comparison operator directly unless you use a  [aggregation function](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#aggregation_over_time) .   sum_over_time(up{instance="instance-1",job="node"}[1m]) gives 12 as result and my scrape interval is 5s.

Comment: @jallen0927, can you explain what are you trying to query here by adding the timerange?

Comment: vinodk, Thanks for replying. The thing I wanted to try is to get a range-vector with records over that time range and with value equals to 1, i.e. filtered by `value == 1`. It's not from a specific task but I was just curious to see if that is achievable while learning PromQL.